# Install remote desktop open license on windows 2019 through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, rdp

I am automating deployment of a windows server 2019 as an rdp license server through terraform. 
I've already added the machine to AD, have installed all necessary features and have activated the license server. I have obtained a rdp open license to apply to the server, but I am struggling to find a way to install the license as `Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack` and `InstallOpenLicenseKeyPack` in particular doesn't seem to support windows version 2019:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/installopenlicensekeypack-win32-tslicensekeypack
When applied, the license version is either 2000 or 2003 based on the 3rd parameter passed.

```
$wmiPack = ([wmiclass]"\\localhost\root\cimv2:Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack")
$agreementNumber = (Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId $Env:CALAGREEMENTNUMID).SecretString
$authorizationNumber = (Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId $Env:CALAUTHORIZATIONNUMID).SecretString
$wmiPack.InstallOpenLicenseKeyPack($agreementNumber, $authorizationNumber, 0, 1, 20)
```

Is there another way? 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that ProductVersion can accept more than 0, 1 or 2. 
In this case 6 is Windows Server 2019